# How to create a master jar file from the subset of gradle dependencies (jar files)

Tags: jar, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following dependencies and I want to create a master jar file that include only 5 jar files from gradle  dependencies(3 jar files from root-project dependencies and 2 jar files from child project dependencies )( I want to include only following files 'spring-webmvc','spring-test' and  'parameters' and two other jar files defined in the dependencies of sub projects in my master.jar file)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':java_farm_core')

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: "$springVersion"
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: "$springVersion"
    runtime group: 'com.fir.param', name: 'parameters', version: '1.0-nep'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: "$springVersion"
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile group: 'com.fir.jide', name: 'jide-common', version: "$jideVersion"
    compile group: 'com.fir.jide', name: 'jide-grids', version: "$jideVersion"
    compile group: 'com.fir.jide', name: 'jide-charts', version: "$jideVersion"

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version: "$springVersion"
    testCompile group: 'org.codehaus.castor', name: 'castor-xml', version: "1.3.1"
    testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.1'

    runtime group: 'com.fir.param', name: 'parameters', version: '1.0-nep'


}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "master Jar file", and why do you need one?

Comment: In our current ant iplementation we unzip all spring related jar files into one directory and all jide related files into another directory and so on, then we create seperate master jar files for each logical group (ie. one master jar file that contain all jide related classes and another master jar file that contain all spring related classes)that include all the classes from unzip jar files, so when we hand over code we hand over 4-5 signed master jar files instead of 100 signed jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Niederwieser, I used the following script but I'm missing something and it's not working, following line is throwing exception 
"from reuterslibs.reuters.collect { zipTree(it) }" . I'm tying to create single master jar file that include all the classes from jar files specified in ext.reuterslibs

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'workbench'.
  Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: file collection.
  The following types/formats are supported:

  - A String or CharSequence path, e.g 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'
  - A String or CharSequence URI, e.g 'file:/usr/include'
  - A File instance.
  - A URI or URL instance.

ext.reuterslibs = [
reuters : [files ("jfl/reuters/ansi.jar" ,"jfl/reuters/jDacsPrincipal.jar","jfl/reuters/jsfc_p2ps.jar" )
]]

```
task reutersJar( type: Jar ) {
    baseName = 'Reuters'

    from reuterslibs.reuters.collect { zipTree(it) }
    //from reuterslibs.reuters.collect { from zipTree(it) }
    //from files {reuterslibs.reuters.collect {zipTree(it)}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution, Now the only thing I'm concerned about is, I want to create a jar file using all the files specified in **ext.jidelibs** which is defined in **dependencies.gradle** and applied to **build.gradle** using **apply from: "$rootDir/dependencies.gradle"**, so now I don't want to define jidelib as configuration and I want to iterate directly over files defined in **ext.jidelibs** and want to create the master jar files that include all content of jar files defined in ext.jidelibs.

```
ext.jidelibs = [
    jide: [
        files ("$jfl/jide/batik-awt-util.jar",
        "$jfl/jide/commons-collections-3.1.jar",
        "$jfl/jide/commons-logging.jar",
        "$jfl/jide/jide-charts.jar",
        "$jfl/jide/jide-action.jar"
                       )
    ]]


// task to generate signedJide.jar
task jideJar( type: Jar ) {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
    baseName = 'Jide'
    from configurations.jidelib.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it).matching {
           exclude "META-INF/*LICENSE*"
           // exclude "META-INF/*NOTICE*"
            //exclude "com/jidesoft/document/document.properties"
           } }
}


configurations {
    jidelib
}


dependencies {  
    jidelib jidelibs.jide
}
```